# How to modify the rows of a matrix, depending on the row (Making a Haar Matrix)

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix, wavelet

I am writing a package that requires making very large Haar matrices ($2^{28} \approx 270$ million rows and columns).  For example:

$$
H_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
H_4 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 \\ 1 & -1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}
$$

(Note that the dimension is always a power of 2)

I have written a function that will build a Haar matrix of arbitrary size (2^J) using Kroneker products.

$$
H_{2N} = \begin{bmatrix} H_{N} \otimes [1, 1] \\ I_{N} \otimes [1, -1] \end{bmatrix}
$$

However, the iterative nature of such an algorithm is very wasteful memory-wise, and takes a VERY long time in `R`.

**THANKFULLY**, the expression of the which values of a particular row should be positive one or negative can be given in closed form, as follows:

---

- For a given value $J$, initialize a matrix of zero with dimension $2^J \times 2^J$
- Set the first row to all ones.
- For all other rows, the `width` of the sequence of non-zero numbers in any given row is
   $$2^{J - \lfloor \log_2(row - 1) \rfloor} $$
- The `start` position for the aforementioned group is
  $$\text{width} * \left((row - 1) - 2^{\lfloor \log_2(row - 1) \rfloor}\right)$$

Thus,

- `positiveOneStart` = `width` * (`row` - 1 - 2^floor(log(`row` - 1, 2))) + 1
- `finalOnePosition` = (`start` + `width`/2 - 1)
- `negativeOneStart` = `finalOnePosition` + 1
- `finalNegativeOnePosition` = `positiveOneStart` + `width` - 1

---

I wrote the following two functions:

```
rowFill <- function(row, H){

  if(row == 1){
    H[row, ] <<- 1
  }else{
    (log2row <- 2^floor(log(row - 1, 2)))
    (width <- dimension / log2row %>%
      round())
    (width <- suppressWarnings(as.integer(width)))

    (start = width * (row - 1 - 2^floor(log(row - 1, 2))) + 1 %>%
      round())
    (startOnes <- as.integer(start))

    (endOnes <- startOnes + width/2 -1)

    (startNegOnes <-  endOnes + 1)

    (endNegOnes <- startOnes + width - 1)

    H[row, startOne:endOnes] <<- (1)
    H[row, startNegOnes:endNegOnes] <<- (-1)
  }
}
```

When I use the idea above in a loop to fill the rows, it seems to work fine.

```
library(purrr)

J = 3
dimension <- 2^J 
row <- 1:(dimension)
H = Matrix::Matrix(0, nrow = dimension, ncol = dimension) %>% methods::as("dgCMatrix")

H[1,] <- 1

for(row in 2:2^J){
width <- dimension / 2^floor(log(row - 1, 2)) %>%
  round()
width <- suppressWarnings(as.integer(width))

start = width * (row - 1 - 2^floor(log(row - 1, 2))) + 1 %>%
  round()
start <- as.integer(start)

endOnes <- start + width/2 -1

startNegOnes <-  endOnes + 1

endNegOnes <- start + width - 1

H[row,start:endOnes] <- 1
H[row,startNegOnes:endNegOnes] <- -1

}

H
```

It works!

```
8 x 8 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

[1,] 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
[2,] 1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1
[3,] 1  1 -1 -1  .  .  .  .
[4,] .  .  .  .  1  1 -1 -1
[5,] 1 -1  .  .  .  .  .  .
[6,] .  .  1 -1  .  .  .  .
[7,] .  .  .  .  1 -1  .  .
[8,] .  .  .  .  .  .  1 -1
```

However, I want to avoid loops, as I am working on a matrix that is $2^{28}$ (really big), and loops they can be very slow. So I thought I'd try the `purrr` package function `walk` to modify the H matrix as a side-effect:

```
haarFill <- function(J){
  dimension <- 2^J 
  row <- 1:(dimension)
  H = Matrix::Matrix(0, nrow = dimension, ncol = dimension) %>% methods::as("dgCMatrix")
  walk(.x = row, .f = rowFill, H)
}
```

However, this does not give me the desired result:

```
8 x 8 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

[1,] 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
[2,] .  .  .  1 -1 -1 -1 -1
[3,] .  1 -1 -1  1  .  .  .
[4,] .  .  .  .  1  1 -1 -1
[5,] 1 -1  1  1  1  .  .  .
[6,] .  .  1 -1  1  .  .  .
[7,] .  .  .  .  1 -1  .  .
[8,] .  .  .  .  1  1  1 -1
```

Can anyone help me see what is wrong?  I have unit tested this thing to death, and I can't seem to figure out where the error is.